# Node and cordova mismatch

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I'm trying to work on a really old cordova project(cordova 4.2.0) in Windows. In order to build the project I need an appropriate `Node` version.

I have tried a few versions from the distributions page by basically hit and trial but in vain. The error is the same.

> 404 for cordova repository www

Which version of **node** would work with `cordova 4.2.0`?

Screenshot here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have installed **cordova 4.0.0** on machine, but your project requires and try to download **3.6.3**, but that version is no longer present on **npm** package.

Use
`npm show cordova@* version` on console to show all available versions of ***Cordova***, then upgrade your project to the nearest one (es. **4.0.0**).